# Yii2 custom form validation

Tags: javascript, yii2

I need to implement custom form validation in the Yii2 framework.

There are following scripts on my page:

```
<script src="/assets/acb8f29e/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/cb9d857a/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/cb9d857a/yii.activeForm.js"></script>
<script src="/unify/assets/js/form.js"></script>
```

Inside of `form.js` we have the function `initProfilePage`:

```
function initProfilePage(){
    $('#form_id').on('beforeValidate', function (e) {
            $('#form_id').yiiActiveForm('find', 'attribute').validate = function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
                //Custom Validation
            }
        return true;
    });
}
```

at the very bottom of the page I have the following script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ( $ ) {
        initProfilePage();    
        jQuery('#user-profile').yiiActiveForm(... here we have the validation parameter which works fine ...)
    });
</script>
```

The form is showing correctly, without any errors, but when I submit the form I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).yiiActiveForm(...) is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that when you are calling the `$('#form_id').yiiActiveForm('find', 'attribute')` you actually pass the function name `find` in the first param and the input to be validated in the second param. But it should not be the `name` attribute but the `id` and that too generated by the `ActiveForm` that is in the format of `model-attribute`.

It throws the error for the `validate undefined` because the [`find`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L278) method returns `undefined` whereas it should return the `attributes` of the input to be validated, and the reason to return `undefined` is either of these

- You are not passing the correct id for the input.
- You are using the `"enableClientValidation"=>false` in your `ActiveForm` config.

To generate the exact name as generated by the `ActiveForm` for the specific field you are validating you can use the [`\yii\helpers\Html::getInputId($model,'attribute')`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#getInputId()-detail).

So to change your javascript like below

```
$this->registerJs ( "$('#form_id').on('beforeValidate', function (e) {
                $('#form_id').yiiActiveForm('find', '".Html::getInputId($model , 'name')."').validate = function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, \$form) {
                console.log('validating now');
            }
        return false;
    });", \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```